# How to center allign input forms

Tags: html, css

In my page I am having one drop-down, 3 text boxes and one submit button .As of now it is left alligned . I need to make it center alligned. I am using bootstrap css in my code. I am new to this field . Can someone tell how to do that . I have tried this:

```
<?php
    echo "<form action=page2.php method=GET>";
    echo '<td><select class="form-control" name="select-val">
        <option value="a1">A1</option>
        <option value="a2">A2</option>
        <option value="a3">A3</option>
        <option value="a4">A4</option>
        <option value="a5">A5</option>
        <option value="a6">A6</option>
    </select></td>';
    echo "<br>";
    echo "<td>" ." <input align='center' type = text class = form-control name = sel_val 
        placeholder =   'Enter  The Name'>". "</td>";
    echo"<br>";
    echo"<br>";echo "<td>" ." <input align='center' type = text class = form-control name = start_date 
        placeholder = 'Start Date(YYYY-MM-DD)'>". "</td>";
    echo"<br>";
    echo "<td>" ." <input align='center' type = text class = form-control name = end_date 
        placeholder = 'End  Date(YYYY-MM-DD)'>". "</td>";
    echo"<br>";
    echo "<td>" ."<input align='center' class=btn type=submit value=select". "></td>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `<input align='center'` use a div and not an input.

Comment: Also, don't use table elements to layout. It is not meant to be used for that.

Comment: since you're using bootstrap; apply it to a custom stylesheet. Everything's on their website. http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: I suggest you make up a new (custom) stylesheet and add the reference under your existing call to bootstrap.css such as "custom.css", and add your CSS rules in there for it. I.e.: `.container { text-align: center; } .center_me { margin: 0 auto; }` etc. Do not edit that big .css file, use a custom file. Using a class can be applied to different elements.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use tables for layouts; it's bad practise if you aren't showing any tabular data.

There are a couple of ways of going about this

Method 1) I prefer this one as it makes the most sense but if you want the elements to be in different rows you can't use this method

On all the inputs and elements you want centered add `display: inline-block`. Then on the container element that encapsulates all of this add `text-align: center`.

This will center all the elements horizontally and should appear how you want it.

Method 2) You can also add a `position: relative` to all the elements and then do `left: 50%; margin-left: -[half of your element width]`. This also works and allows the elements to be on different rows while remaining horizontally centered.